# ¿Cómo subir varias imágenes al servidor con multer en Nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, react-native, expo, multer

Estoy intentando subir un total de 5 imagenes a la vez con multer, estoy haciendo una aplicacion en expo react native, en la cual necesito subirlas, pero al querer hacerlo no me deja:

Codigo:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View,Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet,Modal,ScrollView,Image,FlatList } from 'react-native';
import {widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import { ImageBrowser } from 'expo-multiple-media-imagepicker';
const fotos =(props)=>{
    const uri_fotos = []
    const { navigate } = props.navigation;
    const[visible,setVisible]=useState(false)
    const respuestaopcion =(callback)=>{
        callback.then((photo)=>{
            setVisible(false)
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e)
        })
    }
    const crea_array_foto =()=>{
        for (const iterator of photos) {
            uri_fotos.push(iterator)

        }
    }
    const mover_imagen =()=>
    {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('fotos',uri_fotos)
        fetch('http://192.100.1.1:3000/multifoto',{
            method:"POST",
            headers:{
              'Accept':'application/json',
              'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
            },
            body:formData
        })
        .then((response)=>response.json())
        .then((res)=>{
            if(res.code ==1){
                console.log("se subio correctamente")
            }
            else{
                console.log('Hubo un error')
            }
        })
    }
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Modal visible={visible}>
                <ImageBrowser
                    max={5}
                    headerCloseText={'Cancelar'}
                    headerDoneText={'Añadir'}
                    headerSelectText={'seleccionada(s)'}
                    callback={respuestaopcion}
                />
            </Modal>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.foto} onPress={()=>setVisible(true)}>
                <Text style={styles.titulo_boton}>Subir Fotos</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.siguiente} onPress={()=>{navigate("Ubicacion");crea_array_foto();mover_imagen()}}>
                <Text style={styles.texto_siguiente}>Siguiente</Text>
                <Arrow name={'ios-arrow-forward'} size={40} color={'white'} style={styles.arrow}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
export default fotos
```

Al menos en el front-end no hay error alguno, en otra vista del front-end envio imagenes, por lo que creo que el problema esta en el backend. Aquí esta el codigo de Node.js en donde subo las imagenes:

```
const express = require('express')
const url = express()
const morgan = require('morgan')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const util = require('util')
const multer = require('multer')
url.use(morgan('dev'))
url.use(bodyParser.json());
url.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:'./Imagenes',
    filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,file.originalname)

    }
})


url.use(multer({
    storage:storage,
    dest:'./Imagenes'

}).single('foto'))
//Registro de un usuario
url.post('/registro',(req, res)=>{
    const foto_array = req.file
    const nombre_foto = foto_array.filename
    const nombre = req.body.nombre
    const apellido = req.body.apellido
    const apellido_materno = req.body.apellido_materno
    const correo = req.body.correo
    const fecha = req.body.fecha
    const password = req.body.password


     const query = `INSERT INTO usuario(Nombre, Apellido_paterno,Apellido_materno, Correo, Foto,Fecha_nacimiento,Password) VALUES('${nombre}','${apellido}','${apellido_materno}','${correo}','${foto}','${fecha}','${password}')`
     pool.query(query).then(rows=>{
         res.status(200)
         res.json(rows)

     }

})

url.post("/multifoto",(req,res)=>{
     const multer = require('multer');

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
          destination:'../Imagenes',
         filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
           cb(null,file.originalname)

        }
   })
   var upload = multer({storage:storage, dest:'../Imagenes'}).array('fotos',5)
   uploads(req,res, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.send({code:0})
    }
    res.send({code:1})
   })

})


url.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Corriendo.....")
})
```

Cuando un usuario se registra, este puede subir una imagen de perfil, pero luego puede subir varias imagenes en un album. Sin embargo, al momento de enviarlas no se suben a mi carpeta `Imagenes`, pero en la ruta `/registro` si sube la imagen a mi carpeta.

La variable `uri_fotos`  guarda un array de las imágenes seleccionadas, y lo que se guarda en el array es esto:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "creationTime": 1591222096000,
    "duration": 0,
    "exif": Object {
      "ColorModel": "RGB",
      "Depth": 8,
      "PixelHeight": 788,
      "PixelWidth": 940,
      "{JFIF}": Object {
        "DensityUnit": 0,
        "IsProgressive": true,
        "JFIFVersion": Array [
          1,
          0,
          1,
        ],
        "XDensity": 1,
        "YDensity": 1,
      },
    },
    "filename": "IMG_0996.JPG",
    "height": 788,
    "id": "5710F8F7-D228-4A20-84C0-2A75279A5CAA/L0/001",
    "isFavorite": false,
    "isHidden": false,
    "localUri": "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/120APPLE/IMG_0996.JPG",
    "location": null,
    "mediaSubtypes": Array [],
    "mediaType": "photo",
    "modificationTime": 1591245651987,
    "orientation": 1,
    "uri": "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=5710F8F7-D228-4A20-84C0-2A75279A5CAA&ext=JPG",
    "width": 940,
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo solucione creando un middleware en donde coloque un archivo llamado descargas.js y coloque el siguiente código:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:'./Imagenes',
    filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,file.originalname)

    }
})
const descargas = multer({storage:storage}).array('fotos',5)

module.exports =  descargas
```

en las rutas solo basta con exportar el archivo y colocarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
url.post('/multifoto',multiuploads,(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200)


})
```

Pero el problema es al imrimir en consola req.file salia `undefined`, por lo que concluí es que no es por el bodyparse como en muchos foros decían, sino que el formato de como envías la imagen es decir, de la siguiente manera:

```
const uri_fotos = {
    uri: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=5710F8F7-D228-4A20-84C0-2A75279A5CAA&ext=JPG",//aqui se coloca la ruta o uri de la imagen
    type:"image",//el tipo, puede ser jpg, la verdad es que da igual cual pongas, sin importar si tu imagen es una png u otro formato
    name:'IMG_0996.JPG'//coloque el originalname de la imagen, aunque puedes tambien colocar la uri o ruta, recomiendo primero testear con la uri

}
```

Me falto colocar como enviar un formato de array, es de la siguiente manera:

```
       for (const iterator of photos) {
            formData.append('fotos',{
                uri:iterator.uri,
                type:'image',
                name:iterator.filename,
            })   
        }
        fetch('http://192.100.1.1:3000/multifoto',{
            method:"POST",
            headers:{
              'Accept':'application/json',
              'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
            },
            body:formData
        })
```

Aún así gracias @JhoplaINC por estar al pendiente, espero que les sirva si alguien tiene este problema en común.

Comment: No te olvides de aceptar tu propia respuesta @Jorge

Answer (score -1):

creo que debes cambiar el .single('foto') por: array('foto'). Y eso te permitirá una selección de múltiples imágenes

Comment: en la ruta  '/multifoto'  y ahí especifique el .array('fotos'), en la que comentas es otra que coloque, la cual se usa cuando se registra un usuario.

Comment: url.use(multer({
    storage:storage,
    dest:'./Imagenes'

}).single('foto'))
=>
url.use(multer({
    storage:storage,
    dest:'./Imagenes'

}).array('foto'))

Comment: creo que ese no es el error, verifique colocando un console.log(req.files) y me imprime undefined